# Jenkins plugin only works in dev environment (not packaged as HPI file)

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

We are having a strange issue with our Jenkins plugin.  In the development environment (running using mvn), the plugin works perfectly fine.  But when we install the plugin (using marketplace or hpi file) to seemingly any version of Jenkins, it is totally broken.  Our post-build action (publisher) registers but our configuration form is completely blank.  It only shows the delete button to remove the action.  What could be different about running from maven (hpi:run) vs installing from the marketplace or hpi file?

Comment: All kinds of things could be different.  Start by looking at the Jenkins server log; you should see errors either at startup when the plugin is loaded, or when you try to access the configuration form.

Comment: There are no errors in the logs, they look clean as a whistle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out.  The capitalization of the resources folder that corresponds to the publisher must match the capitalization of the publisher class name.  I think this would probably only be an issue on windows.  Also its strange that it works totally fine in the dev environment.